# JS cookies undefined?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to use JS cookies to turn off a splash screen after an initial load on a website. But JS cookies keeps returning undefined even when I set the value. Basically, the cookie doesn't seem to be saving the value, so the splash screen keeps showing up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (typeof Cookies.get('seen_splash') !== 'undefined') {
    $(".splash").css("visibility", "visible");
    console.log("splash visible");
    $(".wrapper").css({"opacity":"0"});

    /*$(".splash-arrow").click(function()
    {
        $(".splash").slideUp("800", function() {
            $(".wrapper").delay(100).animate({"opacity":"1.0"},800);
            Cookies.set('seen_splash', 'true', { expires: 1 });
            console.log("cookies set to " + Cookies.get('seen_splash'));
        });
    });*/
}

// Set the cookie for 365 days.
$(".splash-arrow").on("click", function() {
    $(".splash").slideUp("800", function() {
            $(".wrapper").delay(100).animate({"opacity":"1.0"},800);
    });
    Cookies.set('seen_splash', 'true', { expires: 1 });
    console.log("cookies set to " + Cookies.get('seen_splash'));
});
```

});

Comment: Aren't you setting the cookie for 1 day? Cookies.set('seen_splash', 'true', { expires: 1 });

Comment: you set the cookie for 1 day

Comment: The cookie is supposed to last for a day right? But it doesn't get saved when i testing within a 1 minute time frame. @JoeAttardi This is case even when I set expires to 365 or 7.

Comment: @AlainIb  
The cookie is supposed to last for a day right? But it doesn't get saved when i testing within a 1 minute time frame. This is case even when I set expires to 365 or 7

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an error in your logic.

When the splash arrow is clicked, you set a cookie of `seen_splash` to be `true`.

The next time around, it checks if the `seen_splash` cookie is not undefined. It was set to `true` previously, which is not undefined, so it shows the splash again.

What you want to check for is if the `seen_splash` cookie is not undefined *and* if it's not `true`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that error! However, the problem is the cookie still isnt saving. console.log("cookies set to " + Cookies.get('seen_splash')); prints undefined instead of printing true

Comment: Could be that you are using chrome in file://?